# Function-like macros without body but different names of argument

Tags: c++, c, macros

The following code:

```
#define MYDEF(x)
#define MYDEF(y)
int main() {}
```

gives me an [error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2tkWInTfbYFP1iqs) (or warning if `pedantic-errors` is disabled):

> 'MYDEF' macro redefined

The reason is different names for unused argument (more over, there is no body in macro). But why? In which situations it can be a problem?

Comment: The standard requires multiple definitions of a macro to be identical. The two definitions above are not identical. They are equivalent, but the standard requires identical. If you want to redefine with a different definition, `#undef` the old macro first.

Answer (score 7):

Because macros are not functions. They are textual replacements done by the preprocessor and can't be overloaded.

It is (almost) similar to find and replace in your editor. Find all the occurences of MYDEF and replace it with (empty string in your case). It's more complicated, of course, but the idea is the same.

And you can't overload this find and replace, can you? :)

Answer (score 0):

The macro can be redefined, and the macro is uniquely determined by the macro name. For example, code like this :

```
#define MYDEF(x)  //the name of the macro is 'MYDEF'
#define MYDEF(x, y) //the name of the macro is 'MYDEF' too
```

`MYDEF(x)` will be redifined(or covered) by `MYDEF(x, y)`, you can't write code `MYDEF(x)` any more after defining `MYDEF(x, y)`

so, if you write code :

> ```
>  #define MYDEF(x)
>  #define MYDEF(y) //(There compiler will give warning). You can write 
>                   //`#undef MYDEF` before `#define MYDEF(y)` to avoid it.
> ```

`MYDEF(x)` will be redifined by `MYDEF(y)`.